# higher partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm confused here:

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y + 4}$$

I got: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} =  x(-\frac{1}{2})(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}2x + 1(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = x^2(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{3}{2}} + (x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ (I used the Product and Chain rule here)
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = -\frac{1}{4}(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} = -\frac{1}{4}(-\frac{3}{2})(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{5}{2}}2x = \frac{3}{4}x(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{5}{2}}$$

The textbook says first, second and fourth are correct, but the other should be:
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = (y + 4)(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$ and
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} = - \frac{1}{2}x(x^2 + y +4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

Can someone explain this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third answer, there should be a negative sign before $x(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$, leading to:-

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right]=(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-x^2(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\\=(x^2+y+4-x^2)(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}=(y+4)(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

For the fifth answer you have incorrectly calculated $\large \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial y^2 \partial x}$ rather than $\large \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$ by applying $\large \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to $\large \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$.

Were you to apply $\large \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ to $\large \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, you will end up with the right answer:-

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[x(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right]=-\frac{1}{2}x(x^2+y+4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the fifth:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial }{\partial y} x(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} x(x^2 + y + 4)^{-\frac{3}{2}}
\end{align}
You can verify that this is the same as $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$.